# Why isn't Google oauth2 giving a refresh token for Client-side applications?

Tags: oauth, google

I've been reading [Google's oauth2 documentation for Client-side applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent). I was surprised that nowhere does it mention refresh tokens. Also, their examples hint that the `access_token` has a default TTL of 3600 seconds. Clearly, I do not want my active users needing to relogin once every hour.

Question: Is there a reason why the Client-side oauth2 implementation doesn't support refresh tokens? Or, is this supported by Google but simply not documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OAuth 2.0 specification prohibits the issuing of a refresh token to non-confidential clients. A client-side application is not considered a confidential client.